# .NET Core VS2019 Build DLL unable to find Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have this a class called ActionGlobals in a project called ComLib. When I reference the dll from the release folder in another solution in another project, I am unable to find ActionGlobals at all. It seems like only several other classes got compiled in but not ActionGlobals.

Am I missing something? I have cleaned, build and rebuild the solution many times, even deleted the obj and bin folders multiple times but I am still unable to get the Class from the referenced dll.

This is all ActionGlobals contains:

```
public class ActionGlobals
{
    public readonly static string LoggedIn = "Logged In";
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between ActionGlobals and the other classes?

Comment: No, this was a weird bug. I cleaned, rebuilt, closed and reopened visual studio many times. However, suddenly it started showing the correct references again. Not sure where it was reading from previously.